# How to unfragment a "molecule"

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx

I have a "molecule" (which is really a graph consisting of 7 nodes) that is fragmented by periodic boundary conditions:

[image]

Essentially, the cell at the center is used to tile the entire space, and even though nodes 1 and 3 share an edge, they appear on the opposite sides of the cell at the center. I would like to unfragment this graph, to get:

[image]

Given

```
bonds =  [(0,1),(1,2),(1,3),(3,4),(3,5),(4,5),(5,6)]
coords = np.array([[4,5],[6,5.5],[6,4],[6.5,1],[1,2],[2,1],[3,1]])
```

and `cell` dimensions

```
cell = [7,6]
```

I try the following:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(bonds)

node = 2

processed = []
moved = []
Q = [node]
new_xyz = []
new_xyz.append(coords[node,:])
indices = [node]
while len(Q)>0:
    curr = Q[0]
    ref_pos = coords[curr,:]
    Q = Q[1:]
    processed.append(curr)
    for i in G.adj[curr]:
        if i not in processed:
            Q.append(i)
                if i not in moved:
                    print("moving ",i, "(ref: ",curr,")")
                    pos = coords[i,:]
                    dist = pos - ref_pos
                    dist = nearest_image(dist,cell)
                    pos2 = dist + ref_pos
                    new_xyz.append(pos2)
                    indices.append(i)
                    assert(curr in moved or curr==node)
                    moved.append(i)

new_xyz = np.array(new_xyz)
```

where

```
def nearest_image(d,cell):
    for i in range(2):
        hbox = cell[i] / 2

        while d[i] > hbox:
            d[i] -= cell[i]
        while d[i] < -hbox:
            d[i] += cell[i]
        assert(d[i] < hbox and d[i] > -hbox)

    return d
```

When I plot the results using:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(5,3))
axes[0].scatter(coords[:,0],coords[:,1])
for i in range(7):
    axes[0].annotate(str(i), (coords[i,0],coords[i,1]))
axes[1].scatter(new_xyz[:,0],new_xyz[:,1])
for i in indices:
    axes[1].annotate(str(i), (new_xyz[i,0],new_xyz[i,1]))
plt.show()
```

I get:

[image]

What am I missing? I don't quite understand how 0 and 2 swap places either. [The full script is accessible here.](https://codeshare.io/nzQVbj)

Comment: What would be your desired outcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you detect that a vertex `u` is too far from a vertex `v` on the horizontal axis, then slide the whole figure by `cell[0] / 2` horizontally. These two vertices are "too far" if they share an edge but are more than half the cell size apart.

Likewise for the vertical axis.

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bonds =  [(0,1),(1,2),(1,3),(3,4),(3,5),(4,5),(5,6)]
coords = [[4,5],[6,5.5],[6,4],[6.5,1],[1,2],[2,1],[3,1]]
cell = (7, 6)

# DRAW GRAPH WITH INITIAL POSITIONS
pos = dict(enumerate(coords))
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(bonds)
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True)
plt.show()

# REPOSITION
dx = (cell[0] / 2) * any( 2 * abs(pos[u][0] - pos[v][0]) > cell[0] for u,v in bonds )
dy = (cell[1] / 2) * any( 2 * abs(pos[u][1] - pos[v][1]) > cell[1] for u,v in bonds )

new_pos = { v: ((x + dx) % cell[0], (y + dy) % cell[1]) for v,(x,y) in pos.items() }

# DRAW GRAPH WITH NEW POSITIONS
nx.draw(G, pos=new_pos, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Initial positions:
[image: graph with initial position]

After repositioning:
[image: graph after repositioning]